# Invalid syntax error

Tags: python, syntax

I'm trying to write a program that calculates BMI by asking what one's weight (in kilograms) and height (in meters) is. Why am I getting an invalid syntax error here?

```
units = input("What units would you like to use? Enter I for Imperial or M for Metric")

weight = input(int("what's your weight?")

height = input(int("what's your height?")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar9vZ.png)

Comment: Count your `(` and `)`... you're missing a couple

Comment: Specifically, you're missing a `)` at the end of the second and third lines.  The second line is where the error actually is, but it doesn't manifest until the third line because it isn't a syntax error until then.

Answer (score 4):

You've picked the wrong order. You should be having `int(input())` not the `input(int())`

And also you have less `)` than you should be. Check that for every opening bracket there is a closing one

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong order of int and input and did forget the closing parenthesis:

```
units = input("What units would you like to use? Enter I for Imperial or M
for Metric")

weight = int(input("what's your weight?"))

height = int(input("what's your height?"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using input() and use raw_input() instead. You also put int() in the wrong place.

Your code should look something like this:

```
units = raw_input('What units would you like to use?....')

weight = int(raw_input("what's your weight?"))

height = int(raw_input("what's your height?"))
```

Comment: Why is raw_input better?

Comment: raw_input() lets the user input character as s string and won't give the user full power over python it only inputs those strings to the system noting more. Its for security reasons that one only uses raw_input. Input() will try to run the input as a python command. The feature has been taken away in python 3, but is still there in python 2.7.